# vuejs contenteditable and backline issue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, ecmascript-5

Hy,
I try to make markdown editor for vuejs but I can use backline (\n) 
in the value of my component ! how in can do this ?

for clean formating of the text like stack or github

https://codepen.io/darkiron/pen/bLgqWN

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editor" @input="send"> {{ value }}
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value'],
    methods:{
      send (event) {
        console.log(this.content)
        if (event !== undefined) {
          console.log(event.target.innerHTML)
          this.$emit('input', event.target.innerHTML)
        }

        this.$emit('input', this.value )

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It's not clear what you ask... please make the question more understandable and maybe include what you expect and the error you get :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/darkiron/pen/bLgqWN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I use textarea :

https://github.com/darkiron/EasyMardownEditor
It's more eazy ;)

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick

```
<pre>{{ value }}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems, the first in your regexp you need to escape backslashes `\\n` in order to add `<br>`

And the second I noticed is that in your contenteditable div you couldn't actually write because the cursor always went in the begining, I guess that was a rendering issue (vue render the text in every keystroke)

Check below.

```js
Vue.component('editor', {
  template: '<div class="editor" contenteditable="true" @input="send"> {{ inp }} </div>',
  props: ['value'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      inp: this.value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send: function(event) {
      this.$emit('input', event.target.innerText)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: 'text with backline' + "\\r\\n" + 'here'
  },
  computed: {
    text: function() {
      return this.test.replace(/(\\r|\\n)/g, '<br/>')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.editor {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <editor v-model="test"></editor>
  <div class="result" v-html="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this not work char "/n" or "/r" are visible. in your editor you don't show this

Answer (score 0):

Have seconde issue : 
the v-model was not update on $emit input type event

Comment: Yes.. you can mark my answer as correct and ask another question on stackoverflow :)

Comment: You don't have understand the issue...  your answer IS NOT GOOD : https://github.com/darkiron/EasyMardownEditor => the good way